# Can not run .exe packed by pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

[My source code](https://github.com/unbeatable-101/Dragon-Game)

I am using pyfiglet in my project and when compiling the .exe it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 358, in get_provider
KeyError: 'pyfiglet.fonts'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dragon_Game.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 65, in figlet_format
  File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 820, in __init__
  File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 827, in setFont
  File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
  File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 139, in preloadFont
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1133, in resource_exists
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 360, in get_provider
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfiglet.fonts'
```

I can't seem to figure out why it won't work, the .py and .pyc files work fine.

Comment: what is the command you are using to package your app

Comment: i suggest to use auto-py-to-exe https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/ it comes with a GUI and very easy to use.

Comment: @ketzoomer I am using pyinstaller Dragon_Game.py from its directory

Comment: @CYREX I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add pyfiglet to your data list in your spec file. You can do this yourself, by editing the spec file. Otherwise, you could build with something like

```
pyinstaller --add-data "venv\Lib\site-packages\pyfiglet;./pyfiglet" Dragon_Game.py
```

Where the path leads to the pyfiglet file inside your PC/environment.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970026/pyinstaller-importerror-no-module-named-pyfiglet-fonts).